# Usb flash drives doesn't recognised after Sysprep

Tags: windows-7, sysprep

I've changed mobo and cpu on a computer. Before change mobo and cpu I've run sysprep.exe.

Everything works fine but now my computer doesn't recognise external drives and usb flash drives.

Any ideas about the problem?

Comment: Post a screenshot of your Device Manager please.

Comment: check device manager and see if all devices are recognized and without error. You probably should install all device drivers for the new mobo.